# Divided tags `li` between the two columns

Tags: html, css

How can, This values divided between the three columns with CSS and `width: auto;` as dynamic?

**As this:** http://img4up.com/up2/20239064020416631754.gif

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/r3rm9/

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A word of caution: You definitely don't want to use `direction: rtl` just for placing the bullet on the right - it should be used for right-to-left text, like Hebrew or Arabic. For example, look what it does to trailing punctuation or leading characters: http://jsfiddle.net/r3rm9/10/ (compare with the source, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the CSS3 Column properties, but support isn't very good at the moment.

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/r3rm9/4/

Comment: You will need a container for the list. I used body in my fiddle, but it can be a div or other block element as well. You cannot use it on the `ul` itself.

Answer (score 1):

This article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/ shows several options for creating multi-column lists, worth checking out. Especially if the numbering MUST be from top to bottom instead of left to right / right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<ul>` a specific width. And your `<li>` and float it.

```
ul {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 50px 50px 0 0;
    width: 207px;
}

ul li {
    list-style-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5PA.png);
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
}
```

Comment: I can not put `width` it should as : `width: auto;`

Comment: @WallStreet can you place a container div around the UL?

Comment: That doesn't give the right order. The right column should be `1 2 3 4`, not `3 6 9 12`.

Comment: @Kobi Yeah, he won't be able to get that order unless he changes the order in which they appear in the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/r3rm9/1/

```
ul li{
    list-style-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5PA.png);
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: I can not put `width: 30%;` it should as : `width: auto;`